# Why does this Button animation happen when the site loads?

Tags: html, css

Alrighty. I'm making a website, and I'm already screwing up. In the process of making a navbar, the animation I'm trying to make is not working correctly.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Roboto;
}

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-height: 50px;
}

nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding: 7.5px;
}

.link {
    padding: 7.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.75s;
}

.linkanim {
    padding: 7.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.linkanim:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

.icocredit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 97.5%;
    font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <a class="link linkanim" href="#test">Test</a>
                
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>

        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="icocredit">Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/"             title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a></div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The button is only supposed to show an animation when a mouse hovers over it.
However, the Button does some weird movement on page load.

Comment: Using JSFiddle it works just fine, showing the animation only when hover it...can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi @TimmSkiller, it works fine on my browser. The button shows background color grey when hover on it.

Comment: I'm testing my HTML in Chrome. And it shows the text (size seeming like 16px) then it like shrinks into the desired size. Can this be a chrome issue? (on page load)

Comment: Does this JS fiddle of your code work correctly for you?  Because it does for me (and presumably the other two posters too...) https://jsfiddle.net/9bnyumcf/

Comment: Yes it does. Weird it shows that in chrome: https://giphy.com/gifs/J05kagwc3sCbDNaLT2

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Yes. Put the html file into a folder, create a new folder inside that folder, call it stylesheets and put the CSS code into that folder and call it main.css. Open chrome, and open the index.html file.

Comment: It's probably the Roboto font finishing downloading and replacing the default font.

Comment: *.linkanim:hover* and *transition-duration* make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's either an issue with the font or with me loading the HTML file locally in chrome, on a real web server this isn't an issue. I'll mark this as the answer and thereby close this question.